# How to Protect Frontend Route in Vue.js and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to protect Vue.js Route for Frontend. I am using Laravel and vue.js for a blog but when I routing for frontend and if admin login and when I hit the frontend url then it's going to login panel so how to prevent this ?

```
let routes = [
        { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default},
        { path: '/profile', component: require('./components/Profile.vue').default },
        { path: '/users', component: require('./components/Users.vue').default },
        //Frontent routes
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/frontend/blog/PublichHome.vue').default },
        { path: '/blog', component: require('./components/frontend/blog/Blog.vue').default },
        { path: '*', component: require('./components/NotFound.vue').default }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using VueRouter, yes? If so you will want to add something like

```js
function guard(to, from, next){
    if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
    else next()
}

let routes = [
        { 
            path: '/dashboard', 
            component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default, 
            beforeEnter: guard(to, from, next),
        }
        { path: '/profile', component: require('./components/Profile.vue').default, beforeEnter: guard(to, from, next),},
        { path: '/users', component: require('./components/Users.vue').default, beforeEnter: guard(to, from, next),},
        //Frontent routes
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/frontend/blog/PublichHome.vue').default },
        { path: '/blog', component: require('./components/frontend/blog/Blog.vue').default },
        { path: '*', component: require('./components/NotFound.vue').default }
      ]
```

Here's a link to [VueRouter Docs Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) on the subject for more info.

Comment: Thanks for you answare